# Make Doxygen recognize "return value hints"

Tags: c, doxygen

In my current project I defined some macros that serve as hints for parameters, return values and the relationship between them.

For example `notnull` is for pointers that are not null. But there are also parameterized hints, like `issizeof(__T)` to indicate that a `size_t` should be filled with the size of the type `__T`. Similar, `GenericPtr(__T)` indicates that a `void*` is returned, but semantically it is a pointer to a `__T`.

They are defined like this:

```
#define notnull
#define issizeof(__T)
#define GenericPtr(__T) (void*)
```

Now I want to use them for a malloc-like function like this:

```
/// @returns a newly allocated memory region for a T
/// @note Terminates the program on failure
notnull GenericPtr(T) myMalloc(issizeof(T) size_t s);
```

Now when I run doxygen, it sees `notnull` as the type and `GenericPtr` as the function-name. If there are multiple parameters, it breaks and thinks each paraneter is a global variable.

Is there a way to tell Doxygen that these hints belong to the type and that `GenericPtr(T)` is actually a type, not a function declarator?

Comment: Doxygen can expand C preprocessor, search its options.

Comment: But in the documentation I do not want expanded macros. The generated documentation should have as the return type `notnull GenericPtr(T)`, as the function-name `myMalloc` and as a parameter `s` of type `issizeof(T) size_t`. If the hints are not paremterized, this works like I want it to